# Does $f(x)=f(1/x) \forall x$ put any restrictions on the derivative of $f$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing, chain-rule

Consider a functions with the property that $f(x)=f(1/x) \forall x \not = 0$ and $f$ continuous.

**Does this tell us anything about the derivatives of $f$?**

I feel like it should, since if $f$ is increasing on $(2,3)$ then $f$ is decreasing on $(\frac{1}{3}.\frac12)$

But I feel like this (and potentially other properties) should be easy to show via application of chain rule/product rule.

- (Another property that I have a hunch may be true is that there is some relationship about concavity/convexity to the left and right of $x=1$)

I recall, however, that $f(2)=g(2)$ does not mean that $f'(2)=g'(2)$ so I'm not whether I can even take the derivative of both sides to use in proofs.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\forall x \neq 0$.

Comment: Taking derivatives, you get $f'(\pm 1)=0$.

Comment: Does $f$ have to be continuous? For example, for $f(x)=1$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=-1$ otherwise obeys your initial condition for any $x\ne 0$, but $f$ is nowhere differentiable

Comment: @PNDas yes it should be, sorry. Will fix when get a chance

Comment: @Andrei I wish assume continuous yes. I will add that when I get a moment. Your example is interesting though. Thanks

Comment: @PQH how is that? Sorry that I do not see it

Comment: Substitute $x = \pm1$ into the answer I posted and solve for $f'(\pm1)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then by the chain rule, we get
$$f'(x) = -\frac{f'(1 / x)}{x^2}.$$

Comment: I made a typo while writing this and (mistakenly) took this further. If I'd caught it before submitting, I'd have probably only made a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be any even function defined on $\Bbb R$.

Now let $f$ be defined as $f(x)=g(\log x)$. Then $f(1/x)=g(\log(1/x))=g(-\log x)
=g(\log x)=f(x)$.

So $f$ will be differentiable, continuous, etc., as the original $g$ was.

Comment: But does this (the final sentence)  only apply for $f$ that are an even function of $log(x)$. Being a function of log(x) seems like a restricted class of functions? (Unless using log(x) is simply a proof technique in which case I apologize for not understanding)

Comment: Sorry, @user106860 . You need to think more abstractly. I started with $g$ and cooked up $f=g\circ\log$. Just apply $\log^{-1}$ on the right to both sides, and get $f\circ\log^{-1}=f\circ\exp=g$. In other words, you start with one of your functions, and get the function $g(x)=f(e^x)$, which will now be even. This shows that your functions are in natural one-to-one correspondence with even functions that are defined throughout $\Bbb R$. The long and short of it? Your condition says very little about the derivative.